# Project Euler #14 code output not coming

Tags: c++

I used the following code for solving problem#14 but for some strange reason it gives no output.Maybe its taking too long to run???
P.S.I know that max is not supposed to be the answer but still there is no output anyways whereas for smaller values like i<100 I get the output.

```
#include <iostream>
long collatz(long);

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
 long i=3,max;
for(i=3;i<1000000;i++)
{
  max=collatz(i-1);
  if(collatz(i)>collatz(i-1))
  {
      max=collatz(i);
  }
  else
  {
      max=collatz(i-1);
  }
 }
cout<<max<<endl;
 cin.clear();
 cin.get();
}
long collatz(long n)
{
int count=0;
while(n!=1)
{
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        n=n/2;
        count+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        n=3*n+1;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: btw... why are you calling the recursive function collatz() multiple times? can't you save the value for i and i-1 in variables outside of the loop? start with collatzMinus1 = collatz(2) outside the loop and set it to the collatz(i) each loop iteration

Comment: @mohaps Where do you see that `collatz` is recursive?

Comment: @Shikhar Shukla Well one problem could be the fact that you are not adding 1 to count, when an odd term is encountered

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an overflow error. There's a particular number between 0 and a million whose Collatz sequence goes higher than the maximum value a long can hold.

Comment: sorry... my bad. it still has a loop though. you can optimize that by saving the value

Comment: @Kevin A `long` is large enough to hold the result.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That depends on the size of `long`. I'm pretty sure the OP's `long`s are 32 bits (Windows or a 32-bit system), and that's too small.

Comment: if you use `long long` and fix your max() calculation then [your solution works](http://ideone.com/QqEPkI)

Comment: Thanx every1 for their precious time and nice advise :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call collatz with n = 113383, you get overflow and n becomes negative from which it never recovers. So you have an infinite loop as it will never be 1. You need to use a long long inside collatz.

However, your collatz functions has other problems as pointed out by others. Also, your logic for the loop in main is not correct. You are resetting max each time through the loop. So, the result you report would be either collatz(999999) or collatz(999998). But that is not be the correct answer.